# How to get fore-edge printing on indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, indesign-scripting

[image]

I need to get a book printed like this. How to get it in InDesign?

Comment: This is not something you do in InDesign. This is something your printer does, based on a simple PDF file you send them of the text/content to print on the page edges. Not all printers have the equipment to do this; you’ll have to talk to your printer to find out exactly how to proceed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: This sounds like it should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done in InDesign, via a script. You basically just need a script that duplicates a text frame onto each new page and moves it ever so slightly to the left on each page. On the first page, the left edge of the text frame touches the right edge of the page and on the last page the right edge of the text frame touches the edge of the page. After placing each of the text frames you can place a rectangle with a paper fill on top of it, so only a thin slice of the text frame is visible at the very edge of the page.

Beforehand of course you need to decide on the text size, then measure and count how many pages you need to create such a height and then you know how many steps the text frame needs to move over.

I have done such a project in the past via scripting, [see here](https://vimeo.com/208117340).

Comment: Does your script adjust for creep? I believe the professional way of doing this is to silk-screen the sides after binding and cutting.

Comment: Well, there is _two_ different professional ways of doing this, one is the one you describe, the other one is using a script like I did. I certainly have seen both on professionally produced books. My script did not adjust for creep, as I did a glue binding with single sheets only (not sure what the correct english term is), but a script could be written to adjust for creep as well. However, one should allow the "slices" to be 2 or 3 mm thick at least, else it will be impossible to produce it correctly.

Comment: Before spending to much time adjusting for creep, make sure to ask your print house if they can do it for you. Most modern RIP software can automatically adjust for creep if you know the bulk of the paper.

Answer (score -2):

You can print on some transfer paper your message/picture and then physically transfer it to the edge(s) of a book.

Comment: Why would you do that when you can make it happen during the print process?