# Indesign: printing on bleeds to reveal a text or image

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, indesign-scripting, bleed

I was wondering if there were any ressource online or script for realizing this type of printing (*Hyperreality* and *Panorama*) on a book's bleed using Indesign.

[image: Effect desired]

[Reference](https://www.merianverlag.ch/en/produkt/kultur-und-gesellschaft/virtual-reality/2e57a4d4-b339-467c-b524-67b56a66a97a.html)

I think this would require a little offset of the *tangential* design on each pages, but I'm not sure about that.

I found this [post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103362/how-to-get-fore-edge-printing-on-indesign), but it does not really specify how it's done

Does any one has ressources or script for doing that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get fore-edge printing on indesign?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103362/how-to-get-fore-edge-printing-on-indesign)

Comment: I'm sorry but I had to vote to close this question as a duplicate. It's pretty much similar to the one you link to. I made an edit to the other question to bump it to the front page.  We'll see if someone has additional info. But I think the comments are right: You should get in touch with your print shop to find out what they recommend.

Comment: Looking at books I've made, I don't think just adding print near the edges of the pages would automatically give a good result. The images exceeding into the bleed only give a very faint coloring of the edges. Printing on the books after they are bound would give a much better result I think. It's also very cumbersome to set up the document and would require extreme attention all the way through production. Your work would have to be very precise, there must be accounted for creep and the pages must be cut more precisely than normally.

Comment: There are various ways to do this. Today, it's often done using specialist inkjet printers. In the past, they used other techniques such as screen printing, even hand painting, and sometimes even guilded.  In my opinion, it would not work with a bleed. In the example image, that edge looks printed, not merely trimmed.

Comment: I found a [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y55rY2IUpeQ) demonstrating an inkjet fore-edge printer.

Answer (score 1):

**I. What is not**

Commercial Print, offset lithography. is in general very exact. It needs to be in CMYK print to align the different plates. But it is not perfect.

Several factors can induce misalignment in one sheet itself.

But things are almost impossible to control at that level when you are folding the paper to produce booklets for a book, whatever the bound type is.

So those letters are not included in your InDesign file of the book itself.

**II. What is**

Those letters are printed when the book itself is finished, trimmed and refined. It could be before hard covers are added, but that is a special case.

So there could be different print methods to do that.

- Some rubber stamp. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=rubber+stamp+print
- Screen print. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_printing
- Inkjet using a gun. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ink+jet+gun
- Spray paint with a mask or stencil.
- You could even try to add a gold foil. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=gold+foil+edge+gilding
- Or some other inkjet system, like the one Billy Kerr mentions in his comment below.

---

Let me complement my answer.

Any page printed on a commercial print never prints ink all the way to the border, because it will produce a mess. So in order to clearly see the image on the side of the paper, it needs the methods I mentioned before. Therefore it is an additional print.

You could do a manual print using an artisanal print method, like screen print, and print also the side of the sheet. Trim it on the other 3 sides and then bond them together using Hot Melt.

---

If what you want is only to reveal the image when the book is bent, I do not know a specific script to automate a frame on the border.

One option could be batch crop an image (or the image of a word) using image magick or Ps, something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169636/windows-batch-file-to-crop-images-in-folder

Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633057/effectively-take-batch-of-images-and-crop-rectangular-slices-of-images-in-numpy

And then inserting it on the border of the page.

Comment: Specialist inkjet printers exist for fore-edge printing. [there's one here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y55rY2IUpeQ)

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I am so primitive. :) But again, it is an additional print. (I stole your comment and add it to the answer)

Comment: Yeah,  I didn't know they existed either until I searched on youtube.